# How to create a checkbox with a dynamic list of values on googlesheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, dynamic

I explain my problem to you :
I currently have a tab on google sheets with my data which is updated every 4 hours. (
rows are added or removed in no particular order)
I would like to create a checkbox column that would act dynamically with the evolution of the list over updates.

Example :
If I check the data box for row 20 and the next update I only have 5 rows of data (so 15 rows have been removed), row 20 will be checked when there is no more data at all

I have browsed the internet and seen quite a lot of solutions related to conditional formatting but this does not answer my request unfortunately

I think google app script can be a solution to explore, your help is welcome.

Comment: I believe what you are asking for is, as the number of rows changes dynamically, only the rows of data have a checkbox.  Now what happens is if the number of rows changed from 20 to 5, rows 6 thru 20 still have a checkbox.  You want those to go away, am I correct?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a checkbox that's dynamically linked to a row's data.

If I 'validate' the data of line 5 thanks to the checkbox and an update adds rows and the data of row 5 is found on row 20, I would like the checkox to be deactivated for row 5 and that it is activated for row 20

to make it simple, I would like the checkbox to be linked to an ID (1st column of my table)